# Trouble Implementing GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api-client, google-signin

I am trying to use Google SignIn on an app I'm creating. I have been using Google's developer tutorials, but I'm getting the error "Class 'HomeActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onConnected(Bundle)' in 'ConnectionCallbacks' highlighted under:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        OnClickListener
```

Here is my HomeActivity code, much of which I used from Google:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import static android.view.View.*;


public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        OnClickListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button mLoginButton;
    private TextView mSignUpLabel;

    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;

    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mSignUpLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblAboutUs);
        mSignUpLabel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "WAY TO SIGN UP MAN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {

        // what should i do here ? should i call mGoogleApiClient.connect() again ? ?

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
                // error dialog.
                showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
            }
        } else {
            // Show the signed-out UI
            showSignedOutUI();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class declares that it will implement `ConnectionCallbacks` which means it's obligatory that you define all the methods included in that interface (and all other interfaces that you wish to implement). Both

Android Studio (Click on the light bulb at the left endge) and Eclipse have to ability to automatically implement uninmplemented methods (you will of course have to fill them up with any custom code)

Comment: Wow I totally knew that too. Thank you so much! That was a major help!